# get values from JSON given by randomuser.me and loop through to append in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

hoping to use [randomuser.me](http://www.randomuser.me) in a prototype i'm putting together (html, css, jquery)

I need to use its api to access profile photos.

I've got this code puling in the JSON as they show in their documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&gender=female',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Now I need to get the url from the picture value in the JSON and write it to the background-image css of a group of divs...I imagine by creating some kind of loop, anybody have an easy to understand way of doing this?

the JSON returned looks like this:

```
"results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "romain",
        "last": "hoogmoed"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "1861 jan pieterszoon coenstraat",
        "city": "maasdriel",
        "state": "zeeland",
        "postcode": 69217
      },
      "email": "romain.hoogmoed@example.com",
      "login": {
        "username": "lazyduck408",
        "password": "jokers",
        "salt": "UGtRFz4N",
        "md5": "6d83a8c084731ee73eb5f9398b923183",
        "sha1": "cb21097d8c430f2716538e365447910d90476f6e",
        "sha256": "5a9b09c86195b8d8b01ee219d7d9794e2abb6641a2351850c49c309f1fc204a0"
      },
      "dob": "1983-07-14 07:29:45",
      "registered": "2010-09-24 02:10:42",
      "phone": "(656)-976-4980",
      "cell": "(065)-247-9303",
      "id": {
        "name": "BSN",
        "value": "04242023"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/83.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/83.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "NL"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "2da87e9305069f1d",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got right you need something like this:

```
$( ".myDivClass" ).each(function( index ) {
   $( this ).attr("background-image", results[index].picture.medium));
});
```

Or if you have in results only one element of array so to do: ...`results[0].picture.medium`...